# How to make http request in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to prevent multiple http requests being fired in my codes.

I have something like

in my controller

```
//if use click, fire this method
var getItems = function() {
    factory.makeRequest.then(function(data){
        //do stuff with data...
    })
}
```

in my factory

```
var factory = {};
factory.makeRequest = function(){
    if($http.pendingRequests.length===0) {
            return getData()
            .then(function(data) {
                //do stuff here
                return data;
            })     
        }
}

factory.getData = function() {
    return $http.get('/project/item');
}

return factory;
```

The above code will prevent the request being fired multiple time if the process is on going. However, I get `Cannot read property of .then of 'undefined'` if I click the button again before the promise is resolved. I know it's because the `$http` request doesn't return anything as I have `$http.pendingRequests.length===0` condition. The above codes give me what I need but I don't know how to prevent the error in console log. Can anyone help me out? thanks a lot!

Comment: so you want to check $http.pendingRequests!==undefined?

Comment: @ABOS yes. I need to know when http request in on the process.

Answer (score 0):

The following will return the current request promise, if it exists, otherwise it will create a new request and return that promise. It will clean up the current request on success.

```
var factory = {};
factory._currentRequest = null;
factory.makeRequest = function(){
    if(!factory._currentRequest) {
        factory._currentRequest = factory.getData()
            .then(function(data) {
                //do stuff here
                factory._currentRequest = null;
                return data;

            })  
    }
    return factory._currentRequest
  }

factory.getData = function() {
    return $http.get('/project/item');
}

return factory;
```

Comment: thanks, but it won't prevent the request being fired multiple time

Comment: It depends what you mean, it should not fire another http request while the current one is in progress, which is what I assumed you needed.  It will just provide promises for the same ongoing request. If you need it to do something else, can you clarify the question?

Comment: My bad, since it won't fire a new request,  factory.makeRequest.then(function(data) will give me an error of can't read property 'then' of undefined.

Comment: The code I provided should always return a promise object. If its null, it creates a new one, otherwise it provides the one for the ongoing request.